# meteor ios cordova ENOET, no such file or director

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor, angular-meteor

Hey I started an app with yeomans angular-meteor generator.
Installed Xcode and followed steps to add ios sdk and plataform to my meteor project.

I have tried removing/adding ios platform.
I have tried changing ownership of my meteor project.
But still no luck. Here is the output of the error:

```
=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:

While running Cordova app for platform iOS with options --emulator:
Error: Command failed:
/Users/donedgardo/marAzul/.meteor/local/cordova- build/platforms/ios/cordova/run --emulator
ENOENT, no such file or directory
'/Users/donedgardo/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/6EB83B1C-FA07-4728-BE3A-CBA81E4707D1/system.log'
Error code 1 for command: ios-sim with args:
launch,/Users/donedgardo/marAzul/.meteor/local/cordova- build/platforms/ios/build/emulator/marAzul.app,--devicetypeid,com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6,--stderr,/Users/donedgardo/marAzul/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log,--stdout,/Users/donedgardo/marAzul/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log,--exit
at ChildProcess.exitCallback (/tools/utils/processes.js:137:23)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)

ExitWithCode:1
```

Comment: `npm install -g ios-sim`

Answer (score 2):

You should chek your mobile-config.js file content. Most or errors are linked to this : maybe your icons or splascreen are not accessible or are in a wrong format (prefer png). 
Clean your mobile-config (or use the standard one from meteorJs) and test it.